# pipenv installs requests different than flask

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

$ pipenv install requests

1. installs requests folder in users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages)
2. installs requests folder in users\me.virtualenvs\\lib\site-packages)
3. in python: import requests
4. command complete successfully

$ pipenv install flask

1. does NOT install flask folder in 
   users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages)
2. installs flask folder in users\me.virtualenvs\\lib\site-packages)
3. import flask
4. gets ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'flask' response

Why did "pipenv install requests" installed in Python but "pipenv install flask" did not? ("import requests" works without pipenv shell but "import flask" requires pipenv shell?)

Comment: Are you sure you're using `pipenv` correctly? It certainly seems like you're not activating the virtualenv before running your python interpreter. ( https://docs.pipenv.org/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project )

Comment: I could have been clear about between 2 and 3. With the requests package, I can import without running pipenv shell, but in order to get flask to import successfully, I need to get into the pipenv shell first. I have no argument with activating the virtual env (that's how we did it with virtualenv, before pipenv). I'm wondering (1) why did pipenv install requests differently than it did flask, and (2) why I do NOT have to activate the virtual env for requests.

Comment: You don't have to activate the virtual env for requests because you've accidentally installed requests on the user level (`users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages`) so the 'global' python interpreter has access to it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but I'm not sure what the difference between my 'pipenv install requests' and my 'pipenv install flask' commands were. Did the install requests activate the virtual env automatically?

Comment: `pipenv install <package>` will automatically install the `<package>` on a virtualenv.  When you ran `pipenv install requests` it didn't actually do #1 on your list, instead, you had at a previous time (accidentally most likely), just ran `pip install requests` causing python to install `requests` on your global python install.

Comment: I could very well have fat-fingered that!  Thanks for the clarification.